# Concatenate two wav files with different AudioFormat

Tags: java, javasound

I have a method that should concatenate two .wav sound files. It works fine if I have two files with the same AudioFormat. But if I take files with two different formats, one of the files will sound really bad in result. So, I need to concatenate two .wav files with these formats:

- PCM_SIGNED 24000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian;
- PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian;

Code of the method:

```
private static void concatenateTwoWaves(String fileName1, String fileName2) {
        String wavFile1 = fileName1 + ".wav";
        String wavFile2 = fileName2 + ".wav";

        try {
            AudioInputStream clip1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile1));
            AudioInputStream clip2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(wavFile2));

            AudioInputStream appendedFiles =
                    new AudioInputStream(
                            new SequenceInputStream(clip1, clip2),
                            clip1.getFormat(),
                            clip1.getFrameLength() + clip2.getFrameLength());

            AudioSystem.write(appendedFiles,
                    AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,
                    new File("output.wav"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `appendFiles` audio stream is just using the format of the first file, `AudioSysten.write` won't understand that the format changes halfway through. You will have to convert all the input files to the same format - [Java Sound Resources](http://jsresources.sourceforge.net/) has example code for that.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you can provide direct example of converting? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the two formats will have to first be converted to the other. Oracle has provided the following tutorial dedicated to this topic, with examples: [Using Files and Format Converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html).

Comment: I cannot recall. Do you deal much with the MIDI side of Java Sound? If you think you're up to it, would love to hear your thoughts on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68197508/418556). Note: I can provide a version of the code with a GUI to make testing (fairly) easy (you just need to provide the text field with a path to a MIDI file).

Comment: @AndrewThompson If I were more experienced with Java's MIDI I might be better able to eyeball possible problems, but unfortunately, I don't have that experience. I gave the question a quick scan and was overwhelmed by the length, and didn't open up the full list of comments. Sometimes with questions like this, the audio part is actually fine, and it's an error in the GUI where the errors reside. A more minimal example could help a great deal with troubleshooting.

Comment: Note that the GUI was added by me, later in the piece. It was about the shortest I could make it and still demonstrate the problem. (Which is 'default sequencer works, other sequencer does not'.) But I was afraid you were going to say that about the MIDI side of it. Oh well. I tried. :)

Comment: Thanks, that documentation helped. I have used `AudioInputStream.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat format, AudioInputStream stream)
` method.

Comment: Happy to help. I think the Oracle tutorials are generally better than the Java Sound Resources, and worth bookmarking. I looked at that JSR doc on conversions, found it pretty sparse. Still, these "Audio Trail" tutorials from Oracle can be pretty challenging. But I think that particular section on "Using Files and Format Converters" is one of the most helpful of the set.

Comment: You should post your solution and mark the question solved! Not many people are going to find the answer buried in this comment thread. I think SO's goal is to be a "reference". Posting an answer will also help people who are volunteers and want to help people to know that there's no further need to spend time here.