# How to select specific Midi Sequencer in Java?

Tags: java, javasound, javax.sound.midi

I'm working on a midi program and want the user to have the option to select which midi sequencer is used if they have many instead of using `MidiSystem.getSequencer()`.

**EDIT**

My code looks like this.

```
public class Demo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sequencer sequencer;

    //Gets default sequencer if only one argument given
    try {
      sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }

    if (args.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    File file = new File(args[0]);

    boolean select = args.length > 1;

    MidiDevice.Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
    List<String> sequencers = new ArrayList<>();
    MidiDevice device;

    //Populates sequencers lists with potential values and prints
    for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
      try {
        device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[i]);
        if (device instanceof Sequencer) {
          System.out.println(sequencers.size() + ": " + device.getDeviceInfo().getName());
          sequencers.add(device.getDeviceInfo().getName());
        }
      } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      }
    }

    String name;

    //If multiple arguments are given select a new sequencer from the list
    if (select) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the number of the sequencer you wish to use");
      name = sequencers.get(scanner.nextInt());

      for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
        try {
          device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[i]);

          if (device.getDeviceInfo().getName().equals(name)) {
            //TODO: This line does not create a valid sequencer
            sequencer = (Sequencer) device;
            System.out.println("Sequencer changed to " + device.getDeviceInfo().getName());
          }
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
          System.out.println("Cannot locate device " + name);
        }
      }
    }

    //Attempt to play midi data from a file into selected sequencer
    if (sequencer != null) {
      if (!sequencer.isOpen()) {
        try {
          sequencer.open();
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      try {
        sequencer.setSequence(MidiSystem.getSequence(file));
      } catch (InvalidMidiDataException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
      }

      System.out.println("Attempting to play Midi");
      sequencer.start();
    }
  }
  
}
```

If you run the program with one argument pointing to a midi file it plays it, but if you have 2 arguments and it asks you to select a sequencer, it is silent. The sequencer is definitely set as the print statement happens and the program doesn't exit immediately as if a midi is still playing, but no noise comes out.

**GUI based MRE**

This MRE converted the command line app to a GUI to be easier to work with.

To test this code:

1. Launch the GUI
2. Ensure the text field (at top) points to a valid MIDI file
3. Select one of the sequencers in the list below
4. Click in the text field to give it focus
5. Activate the action listener added to the field (on Windows that means 'hit enter')

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class MidiSequencers {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    Vector<Sequencer> sequencers = new Vector<>();
    public static String URLString = "https://bitmidi.com/uploads/18908.mid";
        // Used on my local system, given the hot-link had problems
        //"file:/C:/Users/Andrew/Downloads/Queen%20-%20Bohemian%20Rhapsody.mid";
    URL url;
    JList sequencerList;

    MidiSequencers() {
        try {
            initUI();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public final void initUI() throws Exception {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        
        populateSequencers();
        sequencerList = new JList(sequencers);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(sequencerList));
        
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(URLString, 10);
        ui.add(textField,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        
        ActionListener playListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Sequencer sequencer = (Sequencer)sequencerList.getSelectedValue();
                playSequence(sequencer);
            }
        };
        textField.addActionListener(playListener);
    }

    private void populateSequencers() throws Exception {
        Sequencer sequencer;

        //Gets default sequencer if only one argument given
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencers.add(sequencer);

        url = new URL(URLString);

        MidiDevice.Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
        MidiDevice device;

        // Populates sequencers list with available sequencers
        for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
            try {
                device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[i]);
                if (device instanceof Sequencer) {
                    System.out.println(sequencers.size() + ": " + device.getDeviceInfo().getName());
                    sequencers.add((Sequencer) device);
                }
            } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void playSequence(Sequencer sequencer) {
        if (!sequencer.isOpen()) {
            try {
                sequencer.open();
            } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            sequencer.setSequence(MidiSystem.getSequence(url));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Attempting to play Midi");
        sequencer.start();
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            MidiSequencers o = new MidiSequencers();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: So it sounds like none of the names in your "selector" list happen to match any of the names in the "MidiDevice.Info[]" list.  SOLUTION: just populate your selector from "MidiDevice.Info[]",and you should be good to go!

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I've edited the post to show how the box is populated with sequencer names, and it does use the info list. The sequencer is definitely updated it just doesn't work after being updated for some reason.

Comment: Why store string representing sequencer names, when the code could put the actual instances of `MidiDevice` in there? Also, where is the [mre]? Tip: Add @paulsm4 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've uploaded a minimal reproducible example of the bug on my github so you can see the code I'm using and compile it for yourselves.

Comment: *"The demo code is here.."* I'm not visiting an external link. **All code relevant to the problem should be included in the question (site rule).** And again, prepare an MRE or SSCCE. We don't have time to download the entire code, put it into a project and debug it.

Comment: BTW - out of morbid curiousity I *did* visit the Github link and saw 8 classes - meaning 8 downloads. An MRE / SSCCE of a problem like this should be less than 100-150 lines of code and a single copy/paste. If you can't manage to boil the problem down to that, don't expect others (helping for free) to spend time on the problem. After all, you are the only person who actually *cares* if this is solved, for everyone else, it's purely academic. An MRE / SSCCE *can* contain more than one class, but every class that does not contain the `main` method needs to be an inner class or default access.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Apologies, this is my first time so I didn't realise it had to be that small. I've removed all the GUI and got a command line version on the post now. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: That's getting *very* close to code that's easy to work with, but it should take no more effort from the helper to see the code (work or) fail. Please see the edit I made to the question to add imports, change it from a `File` based on command line args, to loading a MIDI off the internet. The edits starts from **Possible MRE** & has further instructions.

Comment: BTW - I just checked that it is not a problem with the MIDI file itself. so I downloaded it from https://bitmidi.com/queen-bohemian-rhapsody-mid and tried to play it from the local file system. **It plays OK.** Is that what you would expect to happen?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Your edit works on my machine, if one argument is given the midi plays and if 2 are given the program is silent. I got no issues with the site not allowing a download. What I expect to happen is that the midi plays if the default sequencer is used and is silent if the selection process is used. That's what's happening on my machine

Comment: *"I got no issues with the site not allowing a download"* Huh.. That's odd, but given it's not the actual problem at hand, not worth further investigation. `//If multiple arguments are given select a new sequencer from the list` I'll try adjusting the code I have to pop an option pane to request a number. It's too much trouble (with my environment) to run code from the command line..

Comment: I reworked the code into a (crude) GUI to make the code easier for me to work with, and can confirm your experience. I.E. the default sequencer plays the MIDI, while the only other sequencer does not, and also produces no errors. This might come down to the problem I've noticed occasionally with the (very frustrating) Java Sound API. It is prone to work fine in one Java version, then various aspects will break in the next.. Ugh.. it's a PITA. I'm not *sure* that is the problem, but will try to alert the only other person I know who's good with this stuff & get them to provide their expertise.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the help

Comment: You're welcome! Please check the latest edit from **GUI based MRE** onward that includes the GUI based code that (on this machine) produces 2 sequencers, the first working as expected, the 2nd silent. It comments out the string pointing to the local file on my system and takes it back to the URL that works the same for you. I've replied to an answer from the person who I regard as an expert, but I cannot quite recall if they limit themselves to the sampled sound API of Java Sound. I expect they'll pop by if they can help..

Comment: .. To get it to play, select one of the sequencer in the list, click in the text field above and hit the enter key. (Make no mistake - it's not well written code, it just includes the bare bones needed to test the problem.)

Comment: Ugh .. my friend replied that it was only the sampled sound side of the Java Sound API he knows about. I doubt it will do any good, but if you notice this comes due to have a bounty added, let me know and I'll raise one. Given the [top two people on Java Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/topusers) are me and the person I was talking about, I really doubt it will do any good, but hey .. it's worth a try. Another thing you might do is raise a bug with the [Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/) at Oracle. I really wish they'd provide a *reliable* sound API..

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: there is no point in letting users choose the sequencer implementation, because if your program uses a standard JDK, there is 99.99999% chances there is only 1 Sequencer implementation available.

Now the explanations of the errors in your program.

**1/ A Sequencer needs to be connected to a Midi output device or a synth in order to produce sound.**

When you use `MidiSystem.getSequencer()`, it is equivalent to `MidiSystem.getSequencer(true)` (see Javadoc), which means the returned sequencer is automatically connected to the default Synthesizer. This is why you hear sound with this instance.

The 2nd Sequencer instance you get is obtained via `MidiSystem.getMidiDevice()`, so you need to do the connection manually (using `Transmitter`/`Receiver`).

**2/ Your code has unintentionally created 2 identical Sequencer instances!**

When you call `MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()`, one of the `MidiDevice.Info` you get is the Info from the Sequencer instance created using `MidiSystem.getSequencer()`. So when you call `MidiSystem.getDevice(info)`, you generate a second instance using the same `Sequencer` implementation (which is actually `RealTimeSequencer` since Java 5).

**Bug fix**

I was able to make your program work with both sequencer instances by replacing `MidiSystem.getSequencer()` by `MidiSystem.getSequencer(false)` in `populateSequencers()`,

and add the connection code below, after `sequencer.setSequence()` in `playSequence()` :

```
        Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();            
        synth.open();
        Transmitter t = sequencer.getTransmitter();
        t.setReceiver(synth.getReceiver());
```

In many years the one and only case I've seen such a similar feature (let user choose Sequencer) in a Java application, it was in TuxGuitar, because TuxGuitar included its own realtime Sequencer implementation, besides the JDK's one (which was awful until JDK1.4, but since 1.5 it's reliable).

Comment: Thanks for the info! *"TuxGuitar included its own realtime Sequencer implementation, besides the JDK's one (which was awful until JDK1.4, but since 1.5 it's reliable)."* LOL

Comment: Thank you very much, I always had a sneaking suspicion that this problem was due to not understanding the documentation

Comment: Can you please mark my post as the answer ?

Comment: Even the OP seems to have abandoned this question, they've certainly visited the site since asked them to accept the answer and neither did that nor commented. So .. I'm calling the bounty early. Thanks for the great answer and congrats on the new rep points.